# Enable background location on Samsung M20?

Tags: samsung, location-services, android-10

Is there a way to allow specific apps to access the (coarse) device location when the location service is turned off?

It seems that on Samsung M20 with Android 10, the "location" button in the status bar (GPS location) needs to be active to allow any location access.

On Huawei Honor 7 with Android 5, for example, it was possible for apps with location permission to access the coarse location without GPS enabled, thereby saving a lot of battery when the precise location is not required.

Can this be achieved on Android 10 as well?

Comment: It isn't possible anymore, but I don't know how Samsung implements. [Here](https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-stop-android-apps-accessing-your-location#android 10-apps) is an interesting comparison between various Android versions wrt location

Comment: This article also confirms that the previous battery saving option is no longer available in Android 10: https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/03/08/android-p-feature-spotlight-location-accuracy-now-binary-setting-battery-saving-mode-gone/?amp

Comment: [Background location is strictly limited in Android 10](https://developer.android.com/training/location/background). There's also an additional permission in Android 10 that *the apps* have to declare: `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`.